# Bluetooth problems on XPS 13

Tags: apt, kernel, bluetooth

I'm running Ubuntu 21.04 on a Dell XPS 13 9300.

All of my Bluetooth devices keep disconnecting and reconnecting.

This is a problem as my mouse, keyboard, and headphones all use Bluetooth. I used to be able to use all 3 at once with no problems.

I tried downgrading from kernel 5.11 to 5.10 with no effect.

The problem started sometime this week.

Attached are all of the packages upgraded in the last 3 days, and another list for all from the last 14 days in case none of the newer ones pan out.

Any idea which of these affect Bluetooth?

Last 3 days:

```
evanmobley@evanmobley-XPS-13-9300:~$ find /var/lib/dpkg/info/ -name \*.list -mtime -3 | sed 's#.list$##;s#.*/##' 
systemd-timesyncd
libcurl4:amd64
qml-module-qtquick-window2:amd64
qml-module-qtquick-layouts:amd64
apport
python3-apport
libmspack0:amd64
systemd-sysv
qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects:amd64
libudev1:amd64
udev
libllvm12:amd64
squashfs-tools
linux-modules-5.10.66-051066-generic
libqt5qmlmodels5:amd64
libnss-systemd:amd64
qml-module-qtquick2:amd64
curl
libgcrypt20:amd64
imagemagick
libqt5qmlworkerscript5:amd64
qml-module-qtqml-models2:amd64
libqt5quick5:amd64
python3-problem-report
ocs-url
libsystemd0:amd64
libpam-systemd:amd64
linux-image-unsigned-5.10.66-051066-generic
qml-module-qtquick-controls:amd64
code
cabextract
qml-module-qtqml:amd64
apport-gtk
linux-headers-5.10.66-051066
libcurl3-gnutls:amd64
ttf-mscorefonts-installer
imagemagick-6-common
linux-headers-5.10.66-051066-generic
systemd
```

Last 14 days:

```
evanmobley@evanmobley-XPS-13-9300:~$ find /var/lib/dpkg/info/ -name \*.list -mtime -14 | sed 's#.list$##;s#.*/##' 
systemd-timesyncd
pulseaudio-module-gsettings
libcurl4:amd64
qml-module-qtquick-window2:amd64
virtualbox-qt
qml-module-qtquick-layouts:amd64
apport
cpio
python3-apport
libmspack0:amd64
linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04
systemd-sysv
qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects:amd64
libudev1:amd64
virtualbox-dkms
libgd3:amd64
ukuu-assets
udev
apt-transport-https
libinotifytools0:amd64
libgs9-common
libllvm12:amd64
squashfs-tools
linux-modules-5.10.66-051066-generic
aptitude-common
libqt5qmlmodels5:amd64
libpam-sss:amd64
firefox
libnss-systemd:amd64
linux-generic-hwe-20.04
firefoxpwa
qml-module-qtquick2:amd64
gnome-control-center-faces
libssh2-1:amd64
libboost-iostreams1.74.0:amd64
pulseaudio-module-zeroconf
paprefs
alsa-ucm-conf
thermald
curl
aria2
libgcrypt20:amd64
imagemagick
libgs9:amd64
libqt5qmlworkerscript5:amd64
qml-module-qtqml-models2:amd64
libqt5quick5:amd64
firefox-locale-en
snapd
linux-libc-dev:amd64
linux-modules-5.11.0-34-generic
virtualbox
linux-headers-5.11.0-34-generic
python3-problem-report
ocs-url
libsystemd0:amd64
libpam-systemd:amd64
libaria2-0:amd64
linux-modules-5.11.0-16-generic
aptitude
libc-ares2:amd64
linux-image-unsigned-5.10.66-051066-generic
linux-image-5.11.0-34-generic
vimix-gtk-theme
gnome-control-center-data
qml-module-qtquick-controls:amd64
wireless-regdb
code
cabextract
linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-34-generic
qml-module-qtqml:amd64
apport-gtk
ghostscript-x
libcwidget4:amd64
ukuu-gtk
google-chrome-stable
linux-headers-5.11.0-34
linux-image-5.11.0-16-generic
linux-headers-5.10.66-051066
libcurl3-gnutls:amd64
ukuu
inotify-tools
ttf-mscorefonts-installer
linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-16-generic
imagemagick-6-common
ghostscript
linux-headers-5.10.66-051066-generic
gnome-control-center
systemd
linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04
```

Comment: What OS & release do you mention; the 5.10 kernel appears 3rd party, and there is mention of a *focal* kernel package which shouldn't belong on a *hirsute* system; what are you running?

Comment: This is on 21.04. I installed the 5.10 kernel manually as a troubleshooting step; 5.11 is the current one pushed out by Ubuntu. The fact that this kernel switch didn't affect it makes me think it is something between the upper levels of the os and the kernel.